# This is a question from GFG. I am trying to analyse and understand this code

Tags: c++

This is a code I have taken from GeeksForGeeks. I am trying to understand the code.

In the line in the function `deleteEle` which says `if(i==n) return n`, how could `i` become `n` if it is running for `< n` times in the `for` loop just above it?

```
    #include <iostream >
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int deleteEle(int arr[], int n, int x)
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == x)
                break;
        }

        cout << i << endl;
        if(i == n)
            cout<<i;
            return n;

        for(int j = i; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        }

        return n-1;
    } 

    
    int main() {
    
           int arr[] = {3, 8, 12, 5, 6}, x = 13, n = 5;
 
           cout<<"Before Deletion"<<endl;

           for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
           {
            cout<<arr[I]<<" ";
           }

           cout<<endl;

     
           n = deleteEle(arr, n, x);

           cout<<"After Deletion"<<endl;

           for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
           {
                cout<<arr[I]<<" ";
           }
    
    }
```

Comment: Because you've `i++` in the for loop preceding it. So if the condition `arr[i] == x` is never satisfied then at the end of the iteration `i` will become `n`.

Comment: On a side note, C++ is not Python. Indentation is irrelevant to C++. So, in `deleteEle()`, after the 1st `for` loop is done, regardless of the `if(i == n)` block, `return n` will always be executed, and the 2nd `for` loop will never be reached. If you want `return n` to be executed only when the `if` is true, you need to use curly braces to wrap the body of the `if`, eg: `if(i == n) { cout<<i; return n; }`

Comment: Please change the title of the question to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could I become `n` if it is running for `< n` times in the for loop just above it?

Because it may happen that the if condition `arr[i] == x` inside the preceding for loop is never satisfied which in turn means that the `break` is never executed in which case the last iteration will increment `i` so that i becomes equal to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

After the last iteration of this loop (`if arr[i] != x for all i in range [0, n]`):

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == x)
            break;
    }
```

`i` will equal `n` if `break` is not executed.